# Fastest way to copy large amounts of data from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I need to copy large amounts of data from an Oracle database to a SQL Server database.  What is the fastest way to do this?

I am looking at data that takes 60 - 70 gig of storage in Oracle.  There are no particular restrictions on the method that I use.  I can use the SQL Server Management Studio, or the SQL Serer import/export program, or a .NET app, or the developer interface in Oracle, or third party tools, or ----.  I just need to move the data as quickly as possible.

The data is geographically organized.  The data for each state comes is updated separately into the Oracle database and can be moved over to SQL Server on its own.  So the entire volume of the data will rarely be all moved over at once.

So what suggestions would people have?

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to insert large amounts of data into SQL Server is with SQL Server bulk insert. Common bulk insert techniques are:

- T-SQL BULK INSERT statement
- BCP command-line utility
- SSIS package OLE DB destination with the fast load option
- ODBC bcp API from unmanaged code
- OLE DB IRowsetFastLoad from unmanaged code
- SqlBulkCopy from a .NET application

T-SQL `BULK INSERT` and the command-line `BCP` utility use a flat file source so the implication is that you'll need to first export data to files. The other methods can use Oracle `SELECT` query results directly without the need for an intermediate file, which should perform better overall as long as source/destination network bandwidth and latency isn't a concern.

With SSIS, one would typically create a data flow task for each table to be copied with a OLE DB source (Oracle) and OLE DB destination (SQL Server). The Oracle source provider can be downloaded separately depending on the SSIS version. The latest is the [Microsoft Connector v4.0 for Oracle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950). The SSMS import wizard can be used to generate an SSIS package for the task, which may be run immediately and/or saved and customized as desired. For example, you could create a package variable for the state to be copied and use that in the source `SELECT` query and in a target `DELETE` query prior to refreshing data. That would allow the same package to be reused for any state.

OLE DB IRowSetFastLoad or ODBC bcp calls should perform similarly to SSIS but you might be able to eek out some additional performance gains with a lot of attention to detail. However, using these APIs is not trivial unless you are already familiar with C++ and the APIs.

SqlBulkCopy is fast (generally millions of rows per minute), which is good enough performance for most applications without the additional complexity of unmanaged code. It will be best to use the [Oracle managed provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) for the source `SELECT` query rather than ODBC or OLE DB provider in .NET code.

My recommendation is you consider not only performance but also your existing skillset.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used the "Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA)" from MS once for this and it actually did what it promised to do:

> [SQL Server Migration Assistant for
>   Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302876.aspx)
>   (documentation)
>
> [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v6.0 for
>   Oracle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43689)
>   (download)
>
> [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) Team's
>   Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/)

However in my case it was not as fast as I would have expected for a 80 GB Oracle-DB (4 hours or something) and I had to do some manual steps afterwards, but the application was developed in hell anyway (one table had 90+ columns and 100+ indices).