# Want to bulk insert Excel file directly into Azure Database using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, powershell

I am trying to bulk import xlsx file into Azure database directly,  i cannot use Blob or ADF or SSIS for this purpose, it has to be excel import into Azure database. I have tried many scripts available on internet including DBA tool but non of them work. The table is already created on Azure DB,

The kind of data i have it does not work well with .CSV or .txt, so i cannot use BLOB or ADF, also, the first i challenge i am facing with powershell is connection, not able to establish connection with the Azure database

Comment: Is there possibility to use python script?

Comment: Yes, however i have heard that python insert data row by row and can become slow as data increases

Comment: check this post for fast bulk loading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216578/fastest-way-to-copy-large-amounts-of-data-from-oracle-to-sql-server, and the speed of loading data is not pointed out in your question

Comment: hI @AKG, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some information in your question is missing. What kind of Azure Database? Can you use SQL?

Use [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) to import the xlsx as an object

`$foo = Import-XLSX foo.xlsx`

use [Invoke-SQLCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) to [structure a query](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-insert-data-into-a-420c399f) based on the data.

```
Foreach ($row in $foo) {
   $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO table VALUES($($row.bar), $($row.etc)"
   invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance MyServer -Database 'TestDB' -Query $sqlquery
}
```

Comment: Hi ncfx, thanks for your reply, however i guess above script will not work if excel is not installed on the server, i have a server where this script has be run, and i cant install excel on it, also do you have a way which in can make a connection string and enter the username and password for Azure and password as a secure string, that is where i m stuck at the moment.

Comment: I can't make any assumptions about your environment, but SQL is prepared on the client side and executed on the server side. This is intended to be run on your local machine to connect to the SQL engine on your server. If you have no way to connect to the SQL engine, how are you using the database at all?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this tutorial: [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#list-of-methods).

There are several ways to import data from Excel files to SQL Server or to Azure SQL Database. Some methods let you import data in a single step directly from Excel files; other methods require you to export your Excel data as text before you can import it. This article summarizes the frequently used methods and provides links for more detailed information.

[image]

BULK INSERT command only support you import csv files.

I suggest you to using [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#wiz).

For example:

My xlsx file:

[image]

The table is already created on Azure SQL DB:

[image]

SQL Server Import data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon, Thanks! for your reply, import export wizard is good for manual work only, my objective is to automate this process in which file keeps on getting imported to Azure DB at a schedule provided that is why i am looking to create some kind of script.

Comment: Hi @AKG, as far as I know, all the scripts do not works for ".xlsx" file. Even Data Factory also doesn't  support ".xlsx" file.

Comment: @AKG, Maybe you can create a SSIS package to [load xlsx file to Azure SQL server](https://zappysys.com/blog/read-excel-file-ssis-load-sql-server/), and then [Schedule the execution of SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-schedule-packages?view=sql-server-2017). Hope this can be helpful.